# How is Realtime Database storage pricing calculated?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently own a Blaze Firebase plan, and I'm planning about using Realtime Database. The *Simultaneous connections* property on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing?authuser=0) explicitly says **200k/database**, but the *GB stored* and *GB downloaded* only say **1 GB** and **10 GB/month** respectively.

So, if I have 4 databases, all having 500MB, will it charge me when adding the storage from all my DBs (2GB in total)? or will it charge me per database (in this case, none of those will generate a charge)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be charged for the **sum** of all the data stored and data downloaded across all of your database shards in that project.  Four databases with 500MB each will be billed as 2000MB total.

Comment: Slight correction: of the 2GB of used storage only 1GB will be **billed**, as there is a 1GB free quota on the paid plan. I'm not sure why the pricing page doesn't show this, but I know for certain that this is the case.

Comment: Thanks to both of us!

**Doug**, how do you know this? Did you experience this yourself?
@FrankvanPuffelen, and if I got at the end of the month 1.3GB, will they charge me proportionally? or will the charge the whole extra GB?

Comment: Doug used to work on Firebase for years, so is quite knowledgeable. :)  
And as I said, there's a 1GB free storage quota on the paid plan, so you'll be charged only for the amount over that.

Comment: So , If I have 2g I will paid 5$ every month !! Or once !?